# Python PIL putpixel TypeError: color must be int or tuple

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a Python script that uses the `PIL` library to render images. However, I'm encountering an issue with the `putpixel` method, which is raising a
`TypeError: color must be int or tuple`. I have a `ray_trace` method in my `RenderEngine` class that computes the color for each pixel, and I suspect the issue lies there.

Here's the code:

```
import argparse
import math
from random import randint
from PIL import Image as PillowImage
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0, z=0.0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    def __str__(self):
        return "({}, {}, {})".format(self.x, self.y, self.z)
    def dot_product(self, other):
        return self.x * other.x + self.y * other.y + self.z * other.z
    def magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.dot_product(self))
    def normalize(self):
        return self / self.magnitude()
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y, self.z + other.z)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y, self.z - other.z)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        assert not isinstance(other, Vector)
        return Vector(self.x * other, self.y * other, self.z * other)
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        assert not isinstance(other, Vector)
        return Vector(self.x / other, self.y / other, self.z / other)
class Color(Vector):
    @classmethod
    def from_hex(cls, hexcolor="#000000"):
        x = int(hexcolor[1:3], 16) / 255.0
        y = int(hexcolor[3:5], 16) / 255.0
        z = int(hexcolor[5:7], 16) / 255.0
        return cls(x, y, z)
class Sphere:
    def __init__(self, center, radius, material):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius
        self.material = material
    def intersects(self, ray):
        sphere_to_ray = ray.origin - self.center
        b = 2 * ray.direction.dot_product(sphere_to_ray)
        c = sphere_to_ray.dot_product(sphere_to_ray) - self.radius * self.radius
        discriminant = b * b - 4 * c
        if discriminant >= 0:
            dist = (-b - math.sqrt(discriminant)) / 2
            if dist > 0:
                return dist
        return None
    def normal(self, surface_point):
        return (surface_point - self.center).normalize()
class Scene:
    def __init__(self, camera, objects, lights, width, height):
        self.camera = camera
        self.objects = objects
        self.lights = lights
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
class Point(Vector):
    pass
class Material:
    def __init__(self, color=Color.from_hex("#FFFFFF"), ambient=0.05, diffuse=1.0, specular=1.0):
        self.color = color
        self.ambient = ambient
        self.diffuse = diffuse
        self.specular = specular
    def color_at(self, position):
        return self.color
class Light:
    def __init__(self, position, color=Color.from_hex("#FFFFFF")):
        self.position = position
        self.color = color
class RenderEngine:
    def render(self, scene):
        width = scene.width
        height = scene.height
        aspect_ratio = float(width) / height
        x0 = -1.0
        x1 = +1.0
        xstep = (x1 - x0) / (width - 1)
        y0 = -1.0 / aspect_ratio
        y1 = +1.0 / aspect_ratio
        ystep = (y1 - y0) / (height - 1)
        camera = scene.camera
        pixels = PillowImage.new("RGB", (width, height))
        for j in range(height):
            y = y0 + j * ystep
            for i in range(width):
                x = x0 + i * xstep
                ray = Ray(camera, Point(x, y) - camera)
                pixels.putpixel((i, j), self.ray_trace(ray, scene))
            print("{:3.0f}%".format(float(j) / float(height) * 100), end="\r")
        pixels.show()
    def ray_trace(self, ray, scene):
        color = Color(0, 0, 0)
        dist_hit, obj_hit = self.find_nearest(ray, scene)
        if obj_hit is None:
            return color
        hit_pos = ray.origin + ray.direction * dist_hit
        hit_normal = obj_hit.normal(hit_pos)
        color += self.color_at(obj_hit, hit_pos, hit_normal, scene)
        return tuple(int(color.x * 255),int(color.y * 255),int(color.z * 255))
    def find_nearest(self, ray, scene):
        dist_min = None
        obj_hit = None
        for obj in scene.objects:
            dist = obj.intersects(ray)
            if dist is not None and (obj_hit is None or dist < dist_min):
                dist_min = dist
                obj_hit = obj
        return (dist_min, obj_hit)
    def color_at(self, obj_hit, hit_pos, normal, scene):
        material = obj_hit.material
        obj_color = material.color_at(hit_pos)
        to_cam = scene.camera - hit_pos
        specular_k = 50
        color = material.ambient * Color.from_hex("#000000")
        for light in scene.lights:
            to_light = Ray(hit_pos, light.position - hit_pos)
            color += (obj_color * material.diffuse * max(normal.dot_product(to_light.direction), 0))
            half_vector = (to_light.direction + to_cam).normalize()
            color += (light.color * material.specular * max(normal.dot_product(half_vector), 0) ** specular_k)
        return color
class Ray:
    def __init__(self, origin, direction):
        self.origin = origin
        self.direction = direction.normalize()
WIDTH = 1920
HEIGHT = 1080
camera = Vector(0, 0, -1)
lights = [Light(Point(1.5, -0.5, -10.0), Color.from_hex("#FF4900"))]
radius = 0.2
spikes = 32
stem_length = 3
stem_radius = 0.008
blob_radius = 0.01
objects = [Sphere(Point(0, 0, 0), radius, Material(Color.from_hex("#FF7701")))]
for i in range(spikes):
    angle = math.radians(360.0 / spikes * i + randint(-2, 2))
    for j in range(stem_length):
        x = (radius + stem_radius * j) * math.sin(angle)
        y = (radius + stem_radius * j) * math.cos(angle)
        objects.append(
            Sphere(Point(x, y, 0), stem_radius, Material(Color.from_hex("#d47721")))
        )
    x = (radius + stem_radius * j + blob_radius) * math.sin(angle)
    y = (radius + stem_radius * j + blob_radius) * math.cos(angle)
    objects.append(Sphere(Point(x, y, 0), blob_radius, Material(Color.from_hex("#febd14"))))
scene = Scene(camera, objects, lights, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
engine = RenderEngine()
engine.render(scene)
```

I'm unsure why the putpixel method is not accepting the color returned by ray_trace. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

## Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\Compressed\Programs\puray-virusmodel\main.py", line 153, in <module>
    engine.render(scene)
  File "c:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\Compressed\Programs\puray-virusmodel\main.py", line 93, in render
    pixels.putpixel((i, j), self.ray_trace(ray, scene))
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1967, in putpixel
    return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: color must be int or tuple
```

Comment: This is nowhere near a [mcve]! Add a debug statement immediately prior to your `putpixel()` showing all the parameters you pass to it.

Comment: There are two `return` statements in `ray_trace()`; they return entirely different types of data.

Comment: `DEBUG: putpixel((0, 0), (0, 0, 0))`

Comment: Ok, so your minimum, complete example should be `pixels = Image.new(...something...)` followed by `pixels.putpixel((...), (...))`